# Expand macro in Latex

Tags: calculations

I have a pretty simple problem but have been unable to look for a simple answer. It's about macro expansion.

Let's say I define 4 symbols:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\newcommand* \A {1}
\newcommand* \B {2}
\newcommand* \C {\A + \B}
\newcommand* \D {\C + 1}

\begin{document}
A = \A, B = \B, C = \C, D = \D
\end{document}
```

The print out is `A = 1, B = 2, C = 1+ 2, D = 1+ 2+ 1`. Is there are way to expand the macros so that `A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4`? I know there is the `\expandafter` macro but its syntax is brutal. I would like to remain within the simplicity of Latex if possible.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! TeX is a typesetting language, so it doesn't perform computations when you don't explicitly tell it to: one wants to typeset `$2+2=4$`, after all.

Comment: You can do this with basic TeX or a package such as `calc`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't want to “expand” macros, but rather to do computations. Expansion is the process by which a macro is replaced by its “replacement text”. So, when TeX finds `\A` it replaces it with `1`; however TeX will never do computations unless precisely instructed to do so, because it's a language aimed at typesetting and somebody would want to print

> 2 + 2 = 4

and this shouldn't be replaced by `4=4` under the hood.

You can easily define a `\compute` macro for doing with integers.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand* \A {1}
\newcommand* \B {2}
\newcommand* \C {\A + \B}
\newcommand* \D {\C + 1}

\newcommand{\compute}[1]{\number\numexpr#1\relax}

\begin{document}
$A = \compute{\A}$, $B = \compute{\B}$, 
$C = \compute{\C}$, $D = \compute{\D}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, `\compute{\A}` isn't really necessary, since `\A` expands directly to `1`.