# TIKZ: foreach not compatible with calc-library?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to draw a set of lines between some set of points, and on the 1/3 and 2/3 point of each line I'd like to draw a vertical line. In order to do this I first defined the points, and then wanted to use a `\foreach` loop to draw. However it seems that the foreach loop does not work with `calc`:

The following code describes what I want to do. The problem is that the expression `($0.333*\x + 0.666*\y$)` within the for loop does seem to cause problems. (While e.g.  `($0.333*(A) + 0.666*(B)$)` works.) Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong/what I need to change in order to make this work?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (-3,1);
\coordinate (B) at (3,3);
\coordinate (C) at (0,3);
\foreach \x/\y in {(A)/(B),(B)/(C),(A)/(C)}{
\draw[-] \x -- \y; 
\draw[dashed] ($0.333*\x + 0.666*\y$) -- +(0,1);
\draw[dashed] ($0.666*\x + 0.333*\y$) -- +(0,1);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parentheses are needed as syntax characters inside the expression of TikZ library `calc`. But the coordinate names can be put into macros:

```
\coordinate (A) at (-3,1);
\coordinate (B) at (3,3);
\coordinate (C) at (0,3);
\foreach \x/\y in {A/B,B/C,A/C}{
  \draw[-] (\x) -- (\y);
  \draw[dashed] ($0.333*(\x) + 0.666*(\y)$) -- +(0,1);
  \draw[dashed] ($0.666*(\x) + 0.333*(\y)$) -- +(0,1);
}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (-3,1);
    \coordinate (B) at (3,3);
    \coordinate (C) at (0,3);
    \foreach \x/\y in {A/B,B/C,A/C}{
      \draw[-] (\x) -- (\y);
      \draw[dashed] ($0.333*(\x) + 0.666*(\y)$) -- +(0,1);
      \draw[dashed] ($0.666*(\x) + 0.333*(\y)$) -- +(0,1);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: That is an even easier solution, thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

You have to expand `\x` and `\y` before you can feed them to the calc library.  There are two ways, see example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (-3,1);
  \coordinate (B) at (3,3);
  \coordinate (C) at (0,3);
  \foreach \x/\y in {(A)/(B),(B)/(C),(A)/(C)}{
    \draw[-] \x -- \y;

    % (1) expand only the point
    \edef\p{($0.333*\x + 0.666*\y$)}
    \draw[dashed] \p -- +(0,1);

    % (2) expand the whole path, protecting everything not to be
    % expanded by \noexpand
    \edef\a{\noexpand\draw[dashed] ($0.666*\x + 0.333*\y$) -- +(0,1);}\a
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What does *to expand* mean here?

Comment: @flawr It means that `\x` and `\y` are being replaced by their replacement text.  You might be interested in these questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248741

Comment: Oh now I see, thank you for the references. Just to be sure: Is it correct that in the second example you define `\a` to be the what is within the `{}`, where everything within the `{}` is evaluated *except* `\draw[dashed]`? (And afterwards we call `\a` to execute it?)

Comment: @flawr Everything inside the braces is expanded but most of it are letters which are unexpandable by definition.  The only thing protected is the single token `\draw`.