# How to return a value from a function in LaTeX3

Tags: macros, expl3, latex3

I have this MWE that tries to return a value from `\l_example_foo_int` from a function:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\returnvalue}{}{
  \int_new:N \l_example_foo_int
  \int_add:Nn \l_example_foo_int {10}
  % return value
  \l_example_foo_int
}

\begin{document}

Should print value here:
\returnvalue

\int_new:N \l_example_bar_int
\int_add:Nn \l_example_bar_int \returnvalue

Should print value here:
\l_example_bar_int

\end{document}
```

It throws an error however.

Wondering how to get it so it can return a value from a function and that value can be typeset or `\typeout` or the like.

Comment: Again you have a \...new instruction inside of NewDocumentCommand..  for your real issue: \int_use:N \foo_int could help..  but using int_add will make the whole thing unexpandable

Comment: If I move `\int_new` outside of the function I still get an error `! Missing number, treated as zero.`.

Comment: The \int_new is not the cause of your problem. .  ... and I am typing on  my smartphone therefore no answer

Comment: Seeing now the real problem (being at my computer at home: `\returnvalue` is unexpandable and can't be fed to `\int_add:Nn` again

Comment: I don't have any experience yet with "expansion" stuff, so I'm not quite sure what you mean, or how you knew that.

Comment: On expansion, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248741/what-does-expanding-mean-in-latex, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35039/why-isnt-everything-expandable, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66118/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-fully-expandable-macros

Comment: You might also be interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56294/86

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\int_add:Nn` is not expandable, i.e. it will not be fed correctly to `\int_add:Nn` again.

I suggest to use two separate commands, one that adds a value and another one, that is a wrapper for `\l_example_foo_int`.

However, the real use case is unclear, so the whole wrapping in `\returnvalue` is not really necessary, most likely.

Don't use a `\...new:N` call inside of a document level macro unless really checking. The next call of the original `\returnvalue` would try to define `\int_new:N ...` again, which is an error.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l_example_foo_int
\int_new:N \l_example_bar_int

\NewDocumentCommand{\addvalue}{}{
  \int_add:Nn \l_example_foo_int {10}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\returnvalue}{}{
  \int_use:N \l_example_foo_int
}

\begin{document}

Should print value here:
\addvalue
\returnvalue


\int_add:Nn \l_example_bar_int {\returnvalue}

Should print value here:
\int_use:N \l_example_bar_int

\end{document}
```

Comment: So this means all variables need to be declared globally then is what im understanding

Comment: @LancePollard: In most cases, yes. If you want to have them local, use `\int_set:N` etc. in a group

Comment: I was hoping to have the function behave like in a normal programming language where you do (a better name instead of `returnvalue` would be `initializeint` lets say for this example) `initializeint` and the output is the result of the function. I would like for it to work like that if at all possible.

Comment: @LancePollard: You fell into a 'normal' programmer trap however. That's what I had to learn some years ago as well: TeX etc. is different. As soon as you perform an assignment the whole thing is unexpandable...

Comment: Ok, need to learn more about expansion then. Thank you.

Comment: Sidenote about global variable declaration. How then do you dynamically generate a variable name at runtime, just use `int_set` or `tl_set`, etc. I'm assuming, no `\int_new` or `\tl_new`

Comment: @LancePollard:  `\int_if_exist:cTF {l_my_#1_ int} {\int_new:c {\l_my_#1_int}{% false branch, if needed}` where  `#1` is a macro argument, for example

Comment: @ChristianHupfer \int_new:N creates always a *global* variable.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I did not claiming something other, did I?  I wrote that they should be declared globally in my cases, otherwise locally with the `\...set:N` etc. macros

Comment: @ChristianHupfer you wrote above "if you want to have them local, use \int_set:N etc. in a group" the etc sounded a bit misunderstable.

Comment: @LancePollard: That's unrelated to your main question, however

Answer (score 3):

`\int_add:Nn` is not expandable (it has no red star in the documentation). So it won't work like this. But you can use \int_eval:Nn:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_example_foo_int
\int_new:N  \l_example_bar_int

\NewDocumentCommand\returnvalue {} {
 \int_eval:n { \l_example_foo_int + 10}
}

\returnvalue\par

\int_add:Nn \l_example_bar_int {\returnvalue}

\int_use:N \l_example_bar_int

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would be helpful to know (1) why you moved `\int_new:N` out of the function, (2) why the need for `\int_use:N` (I read in the documentation that it "recovers the content and places it in the input stream" but I don't know what that means or where it was before the input stream, and (3) if `\int_eval:n` is good-practice (since eval is avoided in some programming languages).

Comment: `\int_new:N` isn't expandable either. If you want a command that can be used in a calculation  it shouldn't contain this stuff.